# How to toggle between 3 elements in React?

Tags: reactjs

The landing page in my app has 2 states: `sign_in` and `sign_up`: `const [loginForm, setLoginForm] = useState(true);`

In my JSX I have:

```js
return (
  <LoginFormContainer>
    <LoginCheckBody />
    {loginForm ?
      // stuff when sign_in form should show
      :
      // stuff when sign_up form should show
     }
  </LoginFormContainer>
)
```

In the `stuff when` I have buttons to switch the `loginForm` state. Now I want to add a third option: `forgot_password`.

I have to change to the `loginForm` to a string and instead of passing booleans, pass string values. But I wondering how to resolve that in the JSX. Now I'm using a ternary condition to toggle between 2 states but that won't work.

I kinda want to use a switch to display a form corresponding to the set value of `loginForm`. Any suggestions?

Comment: One option is to chain ternary operators: `x ? a : y ? b : c`.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict values on your states, I'd suggest that you should have a constant variable to keep your state values

```
const FORM_STATE = {
   signIn: 'sign_in',
   signUp: 'sign_up',
   forgotPassword: 'forgot_password'
}
```

And then you just need to modify your state like below

```
const [form, setForm] = useState(FORM_STATE.signIn); //login state as default
```

*Note that I modified `loginForm` to `form` because of state name alignment*

Here is how you change states

```
setForm(FORM_STATE.signUp) //state values are from FORM_STATE
```

For the rendering part, you can do it this way

```
return (
  <LoginFormContainer>
    <LoginCheckBody />
    {form === FORM_STATE.signIn && <div>Login</div>}
    {form === FORM_STATE.signUp && <div>Sign up</div>}
    {form === FORM_STATE.forgotPassword && <div>Forgot password</div>}
  </LoginFormContainer>
)
```